# Why does this view not display in emulator?

Tags: java, android-studio

I have a feeling this may be a noob question, so please bear with me if so.

My code executes OK, but nothing is displayed in the emulator.  I thought I had created a programmatic view using the below code, but it doesn't seem to generate.

```
        package com.example.trimmer_test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;


public class Trimmer extends Activity {
    public Bitmap img1;

    public static Bitmap TrimBitmap(Bitmap bmp) {
        int imgHeight = bmp.getHeight();
        int imgWidth = bmp.getWidth();


        //TRIM WIDTH - LEFT
        int startWidth = 0;
        for (int x = 0; x < imgWidth; x++) {
            if (startWidth == 0) {
                for (int y = 0; y < imgHeight; y++) {
                    if (bmp.getPixel(x, y) != Color.TRANSPARENT) {
                        startWidth = x;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } else break;
        }


        //TRIM WIDTH - RIGHT
        int endWidth = 0;
        for (int x = imgWidth - 1; x >= 0; x--) {
            if (endWidth == 0) {
                for (int y = 0; y < imgHeight; y++) {
                    if (bmp.getPixel(x, y) != Color.TRANSPARENT) {
                        endWidth = x;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } else break;
        }


        //TRIM HEIGHT - TOP
        int startHeight = 0;
        for (int y = 0; y < imgHeight; y++) {
            if (startHeight == 0) {
                for (int x = 0; x < imgWidth; x++) {
                    if (bmp.getPixel(x, y) != Color.TRANSPARENT) {
                        startHeight = y;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } else break;
        }


        //TRIM HEIGHT - BOTTOM
        int endHeight = 0;
        for (int y = imgHeight - 1; y >= 0; y--) {
            if (endHeight == 0) {
                for (int x = 0; x < imgWidth; x++) {
                    if (bmp.getPixel(x, y) != Color.TRANSPARENT) {
                        endHeight = y;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } else break;
        }


        return Bitmap.createBitmap(
                bmp,
                startWidth,
                startHeight,
                endWidth - startWidth,
                endHeight - startHeight
        );

    }

    private final Resources res;

    public Trimmer(final Resources res) {
        this.res = res;
    }

    public void My_Bitmap2() {
        Bitmap my_bitmap2 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.res, R.drawable.my_bitmap2);
        Bitmap img1 = TrimBitmap(my_bitmap2);

    }

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        ll.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        ImageView IV1 = new ImageView(this);
        IV1.setImageBitmap(img1);
        setContentView(ll);

    }}
```

And the Manifest XML file is:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.trimmer_test">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".Trimmer">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

The view doesn't appear when launched at all.

Comment: are you creating a new layout from the Activity code??

Comment: Yes. Is that a problem?

Comment: Why dont you just create the layout with the .xml files ? that is much easier for future work and more readable. Consider if the current activity have tons of work, CRUD and so on.

Comment: It's because I want to run the relevant Bitmap through the first method and then use it in the view.  That's why.  

Although it occurs to me that it might arguably be more efficient to just modify the Bitmap logo offline and then add it in through conventional XML.

Comment: But theoretically, the above should work, surely?